# ML with Python - extract information from user text

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, prediction, python-3.x

I'm a web developer, got a little experience with Python but none on ML.

Tour operator customer want to introduce AI/ML on his website, the goal is to have a single text input where user can prompt anything to search the catalog, but in the beginning we aim to extract geographical information.

We'll use it to build some knowledge on the topic.

##### Our plan is to:

1. acquire some data
2. (manually) process this data as needed
3. use Python with `scikit-learn` to train a prediction ML model

##### Since now:

1. put online a form with a single text input and had users use it to store what they would write to search
2. for each entry added the expected geographical information we want to extract, e.g.

   - x: "I want to go to Italy"
     y: ["italy"]
   - x: "I'd visit france or Germany"
     y: ["france", "germany"]
   - x: "is there anything for NY?"
     y: ["new york"]
   - x: "surprise me"
     y: []
3. trying to use LogisticRegression on our data

## Is it the correct way to do this?

I've looked online for tutorial and examples, but each one uses predefined datasets like digits or social ads, so anything in the end looks easy and trivial and I cannot get if for my use case I'm going in the right direction.

##### Going further

As a programmer my "long-term" idea is to go modular and train a model for each information we want to extract from users inputs (so we are adding more other expected information, e.g. max budget), this way we will be able to check for emerging or disappearing trends.